# Trying to add a constraint that makes the value on one column depending of another column's value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, check-constraints

On MySQL I have a problem regarding a constraint I'm making on the column "loueur_id" of my vehicle table. I'm trying to make it so when the column location have "disponible" or "en_revision" as value then the value of "loueur_id" become null but if the value of "location" is NULL then "loueur_id" value become the id of the customer who is renting the vehicle

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicule` ( 
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typ` int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 `nb` int NOT NULL,
 `caract` json NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(20),
 `photo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `loueur_id` int, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX per_loueur (`loueur_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY(`loueur_id`) REFERENCES `client`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `vehicule`
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_location CHECK ((`location` in('disponible', 'en_revision')))
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_loueur CHECK (`loueur_id` = CASE WHEN `location` in('disponible', 'en_revision' THEN NULL ELSE `loueur_id` END CASE));
```

This is what I tried to do but mysql said that I've made a syntax error on my last Check constraint. Can someone help me find the problem's solution please?

Comment: `end case`??? What is that?  The second constraint logic does nothing, because `check` constraints allow `NULL` values.

Comment: Since I made a CASE statement, I wrote the "end case" to end it. The second constraint was to put NULL on "loueur_id" not "location".

Answer (score 0):

It is often simpler to express the constraints with boolean logic rather than with `case` expressions. I think this does what you want:

```
alter table `vehicule`
    add constraint ck_location check ((location in('disponible', 'en_revision'))),
    add constraint ck_loueur   check (
        (location in('disponible', 'en_revision') and loueur_id is null)
        or (location is null and loueur_id is not null)
    )
```

Note that check constraints are available starting MySQL 8.0.16 only. In earlier versions, they are parsed without errors, but not actually enforced.

Comment: I tried your solution and I get another error but this time it says that "loueur_id" can't be used in check constraint given that he's already used for a foreign key constraint. Is it a version problem or it's impossible to use a foreign key inside a check constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one constraint:

```
alter table `vehicule`
    add constraint ck_vehicule_location_loueur_id
        check ( (location in ('disponible', 'en_revision') and loueur_id is null) or
                (location is null and loueur_id is not null)
              );
```

Comment: When I  tried your code, I had the error 3823 which said that I cannot use "loueur_id" in a check constraint because it's needed in the foreign key constraint

Comment: @Alexis . . . Alas, this is a limitation of MySQL.  You have to choose between a check constraint and a foreign key constraint.

Comment: So what I want to do is basically impossible with MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.